# How do I get to Drydock Grotto?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In the Silverwastes map, how do I get to Drydock Grotto?

Is it even accessible yet?

I've ran around the map for a while and can't find a way in.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was going to post this question myself. Have an upvote :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The entrance is in one of the new Skritt tunnels that open when you defeat the bandits in the area.
While doing this Living Story chapter (Seeds of Truth), it will show you where the entrance is since it is necessary for the plot.

EDIT:

Sorry, i mixed up the two areas. Here is your answer:
In Picaroon Scratch (that cave next to the WayPoint), there is an event where you have to kill bandits. After that, a gate will open and show you stairs going down to a giant cave:[image: Entrance]
Thats where the waypoint is.
[image: Profit!]

Comment: I have downvoted this answer because I've completed Seeds of Truth and was not led to this area as part of the plot.

Comment: The story takes you to an area very near the waypoint, but you can't actually get to it.

Comment: Cheers, great answer!

Answer (score -2):

[The official wiki](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Drydock_Scratch#Getting_there) explains how you get there:

> Starting from Camp Resolve, go north-west towards Northern Shelf and
>   then east to Picaroon Scratch. Go down the stairs along the eastern
>   wall and then west through the cave until you reach Drydock Grotto
>   Waypoint. If the gate at the stairs is shut, you'll have to complete
>   *Drive the bandits out of skritt territory (80)* first.

Comment: I included the information that you referenced in your post. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.